# Escaping parentheses in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm modifying an array of strings by applying a series of conversions to them. One of the conversions is to swap a country name in parentheses with the full name of that country.
For example:

Foo (GB) -> Foo Great Britain

I have an array of conversion objects of the form:

```
conversion.input_str = '(GB)'
conversion.output_str = 'Great Britain'
```

And I'm trying to do it using regex, as follows:

```
for conv in conversions:
   match_expr = re.compile(rf'(\s|\b){conv.input_str}(\s|\b)')
   converted_str = re.sub(match_expr, conv.output_str, str_to_convert)
```

The \s and \b are there to prevent matches with word internal strings.
All my conversions work except the parentheses one.

If I use the plain `conv.input_str`, I get output of Foo ()

If I try escaping using `re.escape(conv.input_str)` this seems to create the right match_expr but gives me Foo(GB).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with just doing `re.sub(re.escape(input_str), output_str, str_to_convert)` ?

Comment: `re.compile(rf'(?<!\w){re.escape(conv.input_str)}(?!\w)')`